# setInterval with different time duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

Below code initiates a loop for a slideshow. When the first cycle of slideshow is complete, I want to pause on the first slideshow for 6000ms. Under this condition, I want to be able to add the time as 6000ms instead of 1000 ms.

```
this.isPlaying = setInterval(function(){
                self._change(null, "-=", null, self.lineScrollDo, null);
            }, 1000);
```

Comment: You'll have to stop the interval, make a new one set to 6 seconds, stop it, then go back to 1 second. you're better off refactoring it to not use a setInterval. Or possibly include a slideshow that already has this functionality (cycle2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using setTimeout instead of setInterval:

```
var _this = this;
(function(){
  function next(){
    self._change(null, "-=", null, self.lineScrollDo, null);
    var duration = 1000;
    if(/* cond */)
      duration = 6000;
    _this.isPlaying = setTimeout(next, duration);
  }
  _this.isPlaying = setTimeout(next, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: This works the way this code is supposed to work. I want also be able to clear this timeout under certain conditions, like on hover, I should be able to clear the timeout generated by this settimeout. What would be the syntax?

Comment: @web_dev Yes, you can clear it. I modified it slightly. Note that if `self` is already a reference to `this` then you don't need that first line and can just you `self` instead of `_this`. With the modification you should be able to use `clearTimeout(yourobject.isPlaying)`;

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with the `setInterval` method, a different approach might be just to use a counter.

```
(function(){
  var counts = 0, target = 6, self = /* Refer to your object here */;
  self.isPlaying = setInterval(function(){
    if ( ++counts === target ) {          
      self._change(null, "-=", null, self.lineScrollDo, null);
      target = target === 6 ? 1 : 6;
      counts = 0;
    }
  }, 1000); /// <-- needs to be set at offset that will hit both 1 and 6 secs.
})();
```

Obviously the downside of this is you get more executions doing nothing, and achieving different time offsets could be tricky if you can't find a common denominator. But there is less creation and destruction of resources, and would be easier to chain together a number of time switches.

For example, You could have a stack that keeps track of the offsets:

```
var counts = 0, targets = [6,1,2,4], target = targets.shift(), ...
```

And then rather than using:

```
target = target === 6 ? 1 : 6;
```

You use:

```
targets.push( target );
target = targets.shift();
```

Assuming that you want a circular pattern of time offsets, that is.